# "OSError: dlopen(libSystem.dylib, 6): image not found" (OS X + macports + Celery 3.1.7)

Tags: python, macos, virtualenv, macports

I just updated celery via pip (1.5) to the latest version (3.1.7), but I get a fatal exception which I don't understand as soon I try to import the library. By running:

`from celery import Celery` in the shell I get:

```
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/davidezanotti/CygoraPythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/__init__.py", line 130, in <module>
    from .five import recreate_module
  File "/Users/davidezanotti/CygoraPythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/five.py", line 51, in <module>
    from kombu.five import monotonic
  File "/Users/davidezanotti/CygoraPythonEnv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/kombu/five.py", line 47, in <module>
    libSystem = ctypes.CDLL('libSystem.dylib')
  File "/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(libSystem.dylib, 6): image not found
```

I'm using python 2.7.6 with VirtualEnv and macports on OS X 10.8.5

I understand that the problem is that an underlying dependency ("libSystem.dylib") is missing, but I don't know how to fix this issue

(under /usr/lib/ I can find libSystem.dylib on my machine)

Comment: `libSystem.dylib` is the rough equivalent of libc on Mac OS X. The system won't boot without it - something is funky here.

Comment: in fact under /usr/lib/ I've got that lib! …I don't understand :(

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OSError: dlopen(libSystem.dylib, 6): image not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905322/oserror-dlopenlibsystem-dylib-6-image-not-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I had defined a `DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH` in my **.bash_profile**, by following literally the notes about macports in Django documentation on postgis: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/gis/install/#macports

but this leads to unexpected behavior like the one I faced, anyway by commenting it out, all seems to work!

Comment: :( have the same issue, with macports apache (passenger or mod_wsgi, doesn't matter), virtualenv-2.7. but i don't have a DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH env variable.

Answer (score 5):

Just add /usr/lib to DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH will resolve this issue.