# How can I fix a HadoopFileSystem load error?

Tags: python, tensorflow, hadoop

I am trying to work through a few TensorFlow tutorials, and on every tutorial, I run into this same error when either training or testing photos. I tried reinstalling and upgrading billiard, celery, kombu and amqp but have had no luck. The following is the error I am getting:

```
E tensorflow/core/platform/hadoop/hadoop_file_system.cc:132] HadoopFileSystem load error: dlopen(libhdfs.dylib, 6): image not found
```

Comment: maybe this question can provide you with an answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32905322/oserror-dlopenlibsystem-dylib-6-image-not-found

Comment: I am also getting the same error? were you able to fix it?