# How to install h5py (needed for Keras) on MacOS with M1?

Tags: python, keras, hdf5, h5py, apple-m1

I have an M1 MacBook. I have installed python 3.9.1 using pyenv, and have pip3 version 21.0.1.
I have installed homebrew and hdf5 1.12.0_1 via `brew install hdf5`.

When I type

```
pip3 install h5py
```

I get the error:

```
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.19.3 in /Users/.../.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from h5py) (1.20.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Building wheel for h5py (PEP 517) ... error

  Loading library to get build settings and version: libhdf5.dylib
  error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
  error: dlopen(libhdf5.dylib, 6): image not found
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
```

I saw that `libhdf5.dylib` is present in `/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib`, so I tried `export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/lib"` and `export CPPFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/hdf5/include"` beforehand but they don't help.

How can I install h5py?

I am actually installing h5py as a requirement to install Keras.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not a Mac guy, so of limited help. However, I saw a similar question about installing Python packages on Mac M1. He did NOT use pip to install packages. Instead, he used macports, like this: `sudo port install package_name`. Good luck

Answer (score 81):

This works for me:

```
$ brew install hdf5
$ export HDF5_DIR="$(brew --prefix hdf5)"
$ pip install --no-binary=h5py h5py
```

Comment: https://docs.h5py.org/en/latest/build.html#custom-installation for more info

Comment: Happy to hear this worked for others.  This failed for me however with 6 compilation errors (h5py version 2.10.0--Keras compatability).

Comment: it might not be 1.12.0_4 anymore. For me it was 1.13.0. Update accordingly

Comment: Assigning a version tracker with `VERSION=$(brew list --versions hdf5 | cut -d' ' -f2)` after installing hdf5 allows you to select the right directory as in `export HDF5_DIR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/hdf5/$VERSION`

Comment: `export HDF5_DIR=$(brew --prefix hdf5)` is a much simpler way to get the directory.

Comment: I also had to export the include directory:
```bash
export HDF5_DIR="$(brew --prefix hdf5)"
export CPATH=$(brew --prefix)/include:${CPATH}
```

Comment: This works for me on a brand new M1 Mac, and got me on the path to installing Tensorflow which is NOT easy on the M1 Mac.    I had to `pip install tensor flow-metal` followed by `pip install tensorflow-macos`. BUT when I did this, tensorflow-macos installation would fail building the HDF5 stuff. And your post worked and then I got my Tensorflow demo running.

Comment: It cannot hep. Here is the issue "error: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.dylib, 0x0006): tried: '/usr/local/opt/hdf5/lib/libhdf5.dylib' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have (x86_64),"

Answer (score 15):

Try to install h5py using conda. Works for me.

```
conda install h5py
```

Comment: Easy and straightforward solution. Works on my Apple M1 Mac Mini. Thanks!

Comment: worked on a MacBook with M1

Comment: Happy that Anaconda is there for us M1 folks.  They do a pretty good job of getting everything working. Sadly, I can't use Anaconda for every project.

Comment: This works great. I'm not even using Anaconda (and the environment I used this for still is not). This installed h5py and libs onto the system and satisfied the requirement for all my python.org/pip managed environments for tables and other packages as well. I wanted to avoid getting into homebrew on this system, and this was perfect!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some steps you can follow to install `hdf5` on macOS M1.

**Step 0 (optional)**: Uninstall `hdf5` with `brew` if you have installed.

```bash
brew uninstal hdf5 --ignore-dependencies
```

**Step 1**: Install `hdf5` with `brew`.

```bash
arch -arm64 brew install hdf5
```

**Step 2**: Find the directory of `hdf5` and `hdf5.h`.

```bash
sudo find / -iname "*hdf5.h*" # use sudo if possible
```

On my laptop, the output is

```bash
/usr/local/include/hdf5.h
/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.2_2/include/hdf5.h
/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.7.0_2/include/opencv4/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h
/usr/local/Cellar/vtk/9.2.6/include/vtk-9.2/vtk_hdf5.h
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/include/hdf5.h
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.2_2/include/hdf5.h
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/opencv/4.7.0_2/include/opencv4/opencv2/flann/hdf5.h
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/Cellar/vtk/9.2.6/include/vtk-9.2/vtk_hdf5.h
```

**Step 3**: Set `CPATH` and `HDF5_DIR`.

```bash
export CPATH=$CPATH:/usr/local/include/:/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.2_2/include
```

and

```bash
export HDF5_DIR=/usr/local/Cellar/hdf5/1.12.2_2
```

Note that on your laptop, these directories can be different.

**Step 4**: Install `hdf5` with `pip`.

```bash
arch -arm64 pip3.9 install hdf5
```

It then successfully completes the installation.