# cant install h5py on mac using pip

Tags: python, tensorflow, h5py

Cant install h5py on mac

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

have done

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel

pip install versioned-hdf5

pip install h5py
```

nothing working.

Ultimately I'm trying to install tensorflow but that's not working so i tried this

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-1.12.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

but now its giving me the cannot build wheels for h5py error.

Comment: are you on mac m1?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66741778/how-to-install-h5py-needed-for-keras-on-macos-with-m1

Comment: no, im using intel

Comment: Hi @Axe, I am able to install `h5py` module using `pip install h5py` using jupyter notebook in Mac OS. You can install tensorflow by following the step by step instructions mentioned in this [TF install](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#macos) official link or can refer to the similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76289118/21904865). `H5py` module is also builtin with the tensorflow package and will get installed along with the tensorflow.